# How does SOTI's wipeapplication command word on Android?

Tags: android, administrator, soti

SOTI is a remote device administration system that offers a number of features.

One of them is the ability to execute scripts on Android phones remotely, provided that the SOTI client software is pre-installed and configured. The client program does not require a rooted device but it does act as a device administration.

One of the commands allowed in the SOTI scripting language is

```
wipeapplication com.example.notepad
```

This results in all of the app's (in this case a notepad) data being deleted, but not the actual APK file. So it gives you a clean slate for whatever application you specify. I understand that this could be done with root through the following:

```
rm -rf /data/data/com.example.notepad
```

But somehow SOTI is doing it without root. Just as an Android device administrator. Now the Android DeviceManagerPolicy class does have a wipe method, but its not application specific. Presumably, if there's a way to wipe the whole device at a certain permission level, there ought to be a way to wipe one app's data. But I haven't been able to find out which command is being used? How does SOTI do this?

Comment: Some MDM tools (don't know if this is true for SOTI) are signed with the platform certificate from the hardware developer (I assume that is the difference in SOTI between Android and Android Plus devices). With that signature they have deeper access to the system.
But if SOTI works that way is just an assumption that's why I don't post it as an answer.

Comment: did you find a way to wipe individual data like soti does using device administrator privileges?

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall an Android application with bundle ID com.example.notepad , use the following script in Soti Mobicontrol:

```
uninstall  com.example.notepad
```